# dnsmasq gives "unknown interface"

Tags: dnsmasq

I am attempting to run a dnsmasq instance (in addition to the system wide instance on Ubuntu 18). I ran it once and it worked fine. But then I killed it with

```
kill -15 <dnsmasq_pid>
```

Now whenever I try to run dnsmasq I get

```
dnsmasq: unknown interface wlx00c0caa5587f
```

**But** this interface exists in `ifconfig`:

```
wlx00c0caa5587f: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:c0:ca:a5:58:7f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 139  bytes 26260 (26.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 190  bytes 37131 (37.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Here is my config file:

```
interface=wlx00c0caa5587f
except-interface=lo
except-interface=wlp2s0
bind-interfaces

dhcp-range=192.168.33.1,192.168.33.20,12h

port=5777
```

Why can I run this once but not again?

Any help would be great.

Comment: You have better to start/stop the dnsmask as the service. By killing it, you may left some of it's threads keeping the interface on.

Comment: That interface isn't configured (no IP address, etc) - is that expected?

Comment: @roaima you were right. Needed to set static IP. Don't know why. I guess dnsmasq requires that for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `dnsmasq` doesn't like it if the interface doesn't have an IP address. The command that worked for me was

```
sudo ifconfig wlx00c0caa5587f 192.168.33.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Keep in mind two things. This only sets a **temporary** IP for the interface. And the need to exclude this IP from your dhcp range.